# Excel comparison and value addition

Tags: excel

```
Col A  ColB ( Sheet 1)
Tom     1
Lee     1
Tom     1
Sam     0
Tom     1
Jack    0
Jack    1
Sam     1
Sam     1
```

Hi i want to validate with excel formula and get the below result in a new sheet, that is summing up all value of the respective individual from the sheet 1

```
Col A Col B( Sheet 2)
Tom    3
Sam    2
Jack   1
Lee    1
```

Comment: Take a look at the `SUMIF` or, better yet, pivot tables.

Answer (score 2):

There is many ways to do this.

SUMIF is the easiest

in sheet2 ,cell B2 the formula would be

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B)
```

You could also use a Pivot Table or Subtotals